# Как доделать интернет-чат winsock2

Tags: c++, winsock

Сделал интернет чат, указываю ip 127.0.0.1, всё работает. Как сделать, чтобы оно было доступно из интернета?

вот мой сервер

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <vector>
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
int counter = 0;
using namespace std;
vector<char*> names;
std::vector<SOCKET> Connections;
void sendAll(char a[256], int ID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
        if (i != ID) {
            send(Connections[i], a, 256, NULL);
        }
    }
}
void waitMessage(int ID) {
    for (;; Sleep(75)) {
        char buffer[256];
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        recv(Connections[ID], buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);
        std::cout << buffer;
        sendAll(buffer, ID);
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    WSAData data;
    if (0 != WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &data)) {
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int size = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    for (;; Sleep(75)) {
        listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);
        SOCKET temp;
        temp = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &size);
        if (!temp) {
            std::cout << "client ahuel";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "+chelik" << std::endl;
        }
        Connections.push_back(temp);
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)waitMessage, (LPVOID)(counter), NULL, NULL);
        ++counter;
    }
    /*char msg[256];
    recv(newConnection, msg, 256, NULL);
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;*/
}
```

Comment: А у вас есть "белый" IP? Реальный, по которому можно достучаться до вашей машины?

Comment: есть домен который направляет на мой новый ip если он меняется. и да, он белый

Comment: Тогда вроде бы просто заменить 127.0.0.1 на ваш белый ip...